# Command to delete folder from its part name.

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How to get a full folder name from its partial or half name and delete it.
suppose I have a folders in my temp directive

```
scoped_dir3364_20212,scoped_dir3894_27812
```

In those folders scoped_dir is common.i want to delete these directory from command prompt. please tell how to do that

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to your `temp` directory in `cmd` and you could use the `FOR /D` command as below:

```
for /d %p in (scoped_dir*) do rd /s /q "%p"
```

In all cases `for /d` will start searching from the current directory.

[More info is here...](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)